# Javascript: Understanding File interface

Tags: javascript, html, html-input

I'm getting started with Javascript and trying to understand some fundamentals. The questions is not specifically about File interface, but it is what I'm trying to figure out.

In my HTML file I have a file type input.

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" multiple/>
```

Then in my JS file I have:

```
var fileVar = document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0];
```

This works fine and filevar is of type `File`.

Now I'm trying to understand how `files` attribute works.

In W3 the API is defined as:

```
 interface FileList {
      getter File? item(unsigned long index);
      readonly attribute unsigned long length;
    };
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can access the individual File's in FileList by using `files`.
It doesn't seem to be defined anywhere. Where is the array `files` coming from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `files` property returns a [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileList).

`files` is a property of the [`HTMLInputElement` Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLInputElement), that is, the DOM interface for `<input>` tags. It is implemented by browsers that support the HTML5 File API.

To access individual files you can just iterate over them like any other List/Array. E.g.:

```
var files = element.files; //where `element` is a file input element reference
//`files` references a FileList, you can iterate over it and access its File objects
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    console.log('File '+ i +"'s name = " + files[i].name +
        '; size: ' + files[i].size + ' bytes');
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ujelax/8/edit)

MDN has a nice tutorial for [using the File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wasn't aware that it is defined in the DOM interface. I will read on that.

Answer (score 0):

The FileList API is used when working with HTML inputs of type `file`.

Let’s start with a basic HTML input, with an id set to file and type set to file:

```html
<input id="file" type="file" />
```

Traditionally, you would target the input (using jQuery or vanilla JavaScript’s querySelector functions), and use the value method to check for the value of the input. When doing this for a file input, the value method returns a file path:

```html
<input id="file" type="file" />
<script>
  const fileInput = document.getElementById("file")
  console.log(fileInput.value) // "C:\fakepath\waiting-room.svg"
</script>
```

This doesn’t give us any information about the file itself, and if we wanted to use the filename in our UI, we’d need to search and replace for the “fakepath” value at the beginning of the string and remove it every time.

Instead, we can use the FileList API to access information about our files.

The files method on an input of type file returns a FileList object, which contains a list of files:

```html
<input id="file" type="file" />
<script>
  const fileInput = document.getElementById("file")
  console.log(fileInput.files) // [object FileList]
</script>
```

### Finding the length of a FileList

Even if you have a single file attached to your input of type file, FileList still works as an object containing a list of files… it just has a length of one.

To find the length, or size of a FileList list of files, use length :

```html
<input id="file" type="file" />
<script>
  const fileInput = document.getElementById("file")
  console.log(fileInput.length) // 1
</script>
```

### Iterating through files in a FileList

To look at every file in a FileList, you can use the item method, which looks up a file at a specific index:

```html
<input id="file" type="file" />
<script>
  const fileInput = document.getElementById("file")
  console.log(fileInput.files.item(0)) // [object File]
</script>
```

You can also use an iterator, which makes it easier to do something for every file in a FileList:

```
<input id="file" type="file" />
<script>
  const fileInput = document.getElementById("file")
  for (let file of fileInput.files) {
    console.log(file.name) // "logo.svg"
    console.log(file.size) // 680  
  }
</script>
```

Each instance of a file in a FileList uses the File API, so you have access to properties about the files like name, size, and type, as well as access to the contents of the file itself using methods like text, arrayBuffer, and stream.

### Example Codepen

I’ve included an interactive playground for messing with HTML file input and the FileList API as a Codepen embed on the blog post that this answer is from. Check it out here: https://7.dev/filelist-api/